# How to evaluate growth of input size from n to 2n in this case?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics

This is the question I am currently working on
What is the effect in time required to solve a problem when you double the size of the input from n to 2n, assuming that the number of milliseconds the algorithms to solve the problem with input size n is each of the following functions? Express in simplest form possible.
a)log log n
b)n$^3$

Here is how I was able to evaluate part b. If you have a size of n, the runtime would just be n$^3$. If you have a size of 2n, the runtime would be (2n)$^3$ or 8n$^3$. To find the effect in time, I found the scale factor by doing $\frac{8n^3}{n^3}$ which reduced is just 8. By doubling the size of input from n to 2n, the runtime increases by a scale of 8.

How would you do a similar analysis with log log n? With a size of n, the runtime would be 
log log n. And with a size of 2n, the runtime would be log log 2n. How would you simplify $\frac{log log 2n}{log log n}$ though in the same way?

log x analysis After comment by Ross Millikan

$\frac{log 2n}{log n} = \frac{log(2) + log(n)}{ logn} = \frac{log(2) }{ logn} + 1$

Comment: Can you do the case for $\log n$?  You should find it increases very slowly.  Then $\log \log n$ increases more slowly yet.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks for that tip. Can you check my work?

Comment: It is not correct that $\frac {\log 2n}{\log n}=\log(\frac {2n}{n})$.  Check your laws of logarithms for something useful to do with $\log 2n$

Comment: http://www.mathwords.com/l/logarithm_rules.htm Would it be the quotient rule ?

Comment: No, $2n$ is a product, not a quotient.  We are just working with $\log 2n$

Comment: @RossMillikan Does it look right now?

Comment: Yes, that is correct now.  Note that $\log 2$ is a constant and $\log n$ grows, so that term becomes small when $n$ gets large.  This tells you that for a $\log n$ process, the processing time grows very slowly with $n$.

Comment: What would you say though? For $n^3$, I was able to say that the runtime increased by a scale of 8 when the input size went from n to 2n. What would you say for log n? n can be any number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $\log n$ I think the simplest way to express the increase in processing time when the input doubles is to note $\log (2n) - \log n=\log n + \log 2 - \log n=1$, so doubling the input increases the processing time by a constant amount.

For $\log \log n$  I think it is hard to express the increase, but the intuitive thing is that it doesn't matter *at all* when the input size doubles.  If we try to do the same thing as for $\log n$, we get $\log (\log(2n))-\log (\log(n))=\log(1+\log n)-\log(\log(n))$ but that doesn't seem very enlightening.  Maybe it is useful to write $\log(1+\log n)-\log(\log(n))\approx \frac d{d \log n}\log(\log(n))\frac {dn}{d \log n}\frac d{dn}=\frac 1{ \log(n)\ln(2)^2}$ so the added work of doubling the input goes as $\frac 1{\log n}$

Comment: But isn't it $\frac{log 2n}{log n} $, not log(2n) - log(n)

Comment: As I read the question, you are just asked to find a useful way to represent the increase.  The ratio is one candidate, and is a useful way to represent the increase for $n^3$.  For $\log n$, the ratio is not as useful as the absolute increase, so that is why I chose $\log (2n)-\log n$

Comment: Oh ok that makes more sense. thanks. But shouldn't logn+log2−logn be equal to log 2, not 1?

Comment: Yes, but I thought you were taking base $2$ logs, so $\log 2=1$  I believe that is usual in this area.  We don't usually care about multiplicative constants, anyway.

Comment: Oh ok. Why did you introduce the derivative with respect to n?

Comment: It was a useful way to find the change in the function for a small change in the argument, but now I see an error.  You can think of the $1$ as the $h$ in the definition of derivative.  I'll fix it.

Comment: for "but the intuitive thing is that it doesn't matter at all when the input size doubles", can we say this intuitively because of how small the change was for the log function?

Comment: That and the fact that log log grows even slower than log.

Comment: And for log, we know it the runtime will by some constant amount, but we don't know exactly what that constant amount is?